# Beautiful Soup not returning everything in HTML file?

Tags: python, html

HTML noob here, so I could be misunderstanding something about the HTML document, so bear with me.

I'm using Beautiful Soup to parse web data in Python. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/"
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page)
indicateGameDone = str(soup.find("div", {"class": "nbaModTopStatus"}))
print indicateGameDone
```

now, if you look at the website, the HTML code has the line `<p class="nbaLiveStatTxSm"> FINAL </p>`, (inspect the 'Final' text on the left side of the container on the first ATL-WAS game on the page to see it for youself.) But when I run the code above, my code doesn't return the 'FINAL' that is seen on the webpage, and instead the `nbaLiveStatTxSm` class is empty.

On my machine, this is the output when I print `indicateGameDone`:

`<div class="nbaModTopStatus"><p class="nbaLiveStatTx">Live</p><p class="nbaLiveStatTxSm"></p><p class="nbaFnlStatTx">Final</p><p class="nbaFnlStatTxSm"></p></div>`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: clarification: the problem isn't retrieving the text within the tag, the problem is that when I take the html code from the website and print it out in python, something that I saw when I inspected the element on the web is not there in the print statement in Python.

Comment: i *think* it could be because you're turning the WebElement object into a string - which is not what ought to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. changed the import of beautifulsoup to the proper syntax for the current version of BeautifulSoup
2. corrected the way you were constructing the BeautifulSoup object
3. fixed your `find` statement, then used the `.text` command to get the string representation of the text in the HTML you're after.

With some minor modifications to your code as listed above, your code runs for me.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/"
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
indicateGameDone = soup.find("div", {"class": "nbaModTopStatus"})
print indicateGameDone.text ## "LiveFinal "
```

to address comments:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/"
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
indicateGameDone = soup.find("p", {"class": "nbaFnlStatTx"})
print indicateGameDone.text
```

Comment: Can you post what is printed out on your machine? This still isn't working for me

Comment: What prints out on my machine is indicated in the comment after the last line - I get a string that says "LiveFinal".  What exactly does your code do? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I get as well. However what I am looking for is it to output 'FINAL' which is in the body of the `nbaLiveStatTxSm` p class at http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/

Comment: I've added how to find that in to my original answer.

Comment: @AdlaiAbdelrazaq did this work? When I took a look at this urllib was returning the tag as empty so beautiful soup certainly wouldn't be able to find the text....

Comment: @TylerS, he wanted a `p` tag contained within that `p` tag. Trivial issue to fix up.

Comment: It didn't, I just accepted it because after several times of trying to re-explain, the people helping still didn't understand. This is the problem, that it's returning an empty tag, but when I inspect the element on the web, it displays as not empty. I need the information that's within that specific tag (`nbaLiveStatTxSm`) and don't know how to get it/why it isn't returning the text inside the tag.

Comment: @AdlaiAbdelrazaq , I explained the problem.  The `p` tag you're targeting *contains* the `p` tag that holds the text you're after.

Comment: @n1c9 I know, I posted the question incorrectly, my apologies. However, if you run the second block of code that you posted (the one that searches for `nbaFnlStatTx`) it prints nothing. However if you inspect element on `http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/` , and do a search for `nbaFnlStatTx`,  you will notice that it says 'FINAL' in each of the instances of the `nbaFnlStatTx` `p` tag. My question is why does it display on the website but not in the Python code.

Comment: when i run the code in the second block, it returns 'Final' for me just fine.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nsE6q3o.png is that what you see (roughly) when you run it, @AdlaiAbdelrazaq ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave you the wrong `p` tag. It should be `nbaLiveStatTxSm` instead of `nbaFnlStatTx`

Comment: `<p class="nbaLiveStatTxSm"></p>` is how it shows up in the page source.  It doesn't contain any text.

Comment: http://imgur.com/HYNU2fd

This is what I see when I inspect the page source and search for `nbaLiveStatTxSm`

Comment: Really odd. Sometimes when I load the page it has it, sometimes it doesn't.  I'm stumped to be dead honest.

Comment: @n1c9 Thanks for your help anyways. Working with this site is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Again...the problem isn't with Beautiful Soup. If you look at what urllib is returning, the tag is blank. Try using a different library or manually send a request to see if you can fix it.

Comment: @TylerS Not blaming beautiful soup. I think there's probably something going on in the HTML file that I'm not seeing or understanding and thats the perspective I'm asking from. As you said, both urllib and BeautifulSoup both don't return anything in the tag I'm looking at.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic to extract any text. 
This code allows you to extract any data between any tags.
Output - FINAL

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/"
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
indicateGameDone = soup.find("div", {"class": "nbaFnlStatTx"})
for p in indicateGameDone:
    p_text = soup.find("p", {"class": "nbaFnlStatTxSm"})
    print(p_text.getText())
    break;
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over a single WebElement?

Comment: I wrote more generalised code and moreover with this you can get any tag between the outer div. That's why.

Comment: When run, this code doesn't output anything. What you're going for is something like `for p in indicateGameDone.find_all('p'):
print p.text`

Comment: Hi, Please check it now. :) Wrote the wrong class name.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is not with BeautifulSoup but instead with urllib.

Try running the following commands

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url = "http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160323/"
>>> page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
>>> page.find('<div class="nbaModTopStatus">')
44230
```

Which is no surprise considering that Beautiful Soup was able to find the div itself. However when we look a little deeper into what urllib is actually collecting we can see that the `<p class="nbaFnlStatTxSm">` is empty by running

```
>>> page[44230:45000]
'<div class="nbaModTopStatus"><p class="nbaLiveStatTx">Live</p><p class="nbaLiveStatTxSm"></p><p class="nbaFnlStatTx">Final</p><p class="nbaFnlStatTxSm"></p></div><div id="nbaGLBroadcast"><a href="/leaguepass"><img src="/.element/img/3.0/sect/gameline/broadcasters/lp.png"></a></div><div class="nbaTeamsRow"><div class="nbaModTopTeamScr nbaModTopTeamAw"><h5 class="nbaModTopTeamName awayteam">ATL</h5><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/gameline/teams/ATL.gif" width="34" height="22" title="Atlanta Hawks"><h4 class="nbaModTopTeamNum  win"></h4></div><div class="nbaModTopTeamScr nbaModTopTeamHm"><h5 class="nbaModTopTeamName hometeam">WAS</h5><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/img/2.0/sect/gameline/teams/WAS.gif" width="34" '
```

You can see that the tag is empty, so your problem is the data that's being passed to Beautiful Soup, not the package itself.